# Set route on a map using Indoo.rs ios sdk

Tags: ios, swift, indoor-positioning-system

I am using Indoo.rs ios sdk by swift to build a small app showing my map, the issue is I have no idea to write a code to set route between 2 point on the map, I came across the documentation but no result ... here is my code :

The documentation is here : https://indoors.readme.io/docs/routing-1

Please if there is any idea share with me.
Thanks

```
import UIKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , RoutingDelegate ,IndoorsServiceDelegate, ISIndoorsSurfaceViewControllerDelegate ,IndoorsSurfaceViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var SetRouteButton: UIButton!

    var _currentBuilding: IDSBuilding?
    var dot  : ISIndoorsSurface?
    var _indoorsSurfaceViewController: ISIndoorsSurfaceViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // API key of the cloud application
        _ = Indoors(licenseKey: "My_API_KEY" , andServiceDelegate: nil)
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController = ISIndoorsSurfaceViewController()
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.delegate = self


        // Enabling dotOnRail Mode
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.dotOnRailsJumpingDistance = 55000
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.enableDotOnRails = true


        // show currunt postion
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.showsUserPosition = true




        // Load the map in a view holding it
        addSurfaceAsChildViewController()
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.loadBuildingWithBuildingId(MyBuildingId)


        // Route snaping
        Indoors.instance().enablePredefinedRouteSnapping()


        // Display All Zones
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.setZoneDisplayMode(IndoorsSurfaceZoneDisplayModeAllAvailable)


        // Set visible map
        let mapRect: CGRect = _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.visibleMapRect
        _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, animated: true)


        // Filters
        Indoors.instance().enableStabilisationFilter = true
        Indoors.instance().stabilisationFilterTime = 4000



    }







// Add the map to the view controller
func addSurfaceAsChildViewController () {
    self.addChildViewController(_indoorsSurfaceViewController!)
    //_indoorsSurfaceViewController!.view.frame = self.view.frame
    _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.7)

    self.view.addSubview(_indoorsSurfaceViewController!.view)
    _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}


func buildingLoaded(building : IDSBuilding!) {
    _currentBuilding = building
    self.calculateRoute(_currentBuilding)
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
}


func calculateRoute(building : IDSBuilding!) {
    let start = IDSCoordinate(x: 1, andY: 111, andFloorLevel: 0);
    let end = IDSCoordinate(x: 1, andY: 111, andFloorLevel: 0);
    let path = [start, end]


    Indoors.instance().routeFromLocation(start, toLocation: end, inBuilding: building, delegate: self)
    self.setRoute(path)

}

// MARK: RoutingDelegate

func setRoute(path: [AnyObject]!) {
    _indoorsSurfaceViewController!.surfaceView.showPathWithPoints(path)
}



}
```

extension ViewController {
    // MARK: ISIndoorsSurfaceViewControllerDelegate

```
func indoorsSurfaceViewController(indoorsSurfaceViewController: ISIndoorsSurfaceViewController!, isLoadingBuildingWithBuildingId buildingId: UInt, progress: UInt) {
    NSLog("Building loading progress: %lu", progress)
}

func indoorsSurfaceViewController(indoorsSurfaceViewController: ISIndoorsSurfaceViewController!, didFinishLoadingBuilding building: IDSBuilding!) {
    NSLog("Building loaded successfully!")

    // By Mohammed Hassan
    UIAlertView(title: "Indoors", message: "Building loaded successfully!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "ok").show()




}

func indoorsSurfaceViewController(indoorsSurfaceViewController: ISIndoorsSurfaceViewController!, didFailLoadingBuildingWithBuildingId buildingId: UInt, error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Loading building failed with error: %@", error)

    UIAlertView(title: error!.localizedDescription, message: error!.localizedFailureReason!, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "ok").show()
}

// MARK: IndoorsServiceDelegate

func onError(indoorsError: IndoorsError!) {

}

func locationAuthorizationStatusDidChange(status: IDSLocationAuthorizationStatus) {




}

func bluetoothStateDidChange(bluetoothState: IDSBluetoothState) {


}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked shows that the points are not simple arrays of integers (that would be weird, imo). You're casting the array point to an array of AnyObjects (still not points, and since you used integers it won't work anyways) and pass that. You need to construct an array of `IDSCoordinate`s (for start and end) to use as path. Like the documentation suggests (converted to swift):

```
var start = IDSCoordinate(x: 1234, andY: 1234, andFloorLevel: 0)
var end = IDSCoordinate(x: 12345, andY: 12345, andFloorLevel: 0)
// 1234 and so on are example values, that depends on your context

Indoors.instance().routeFromLocation(start, toLocation: end, delegate:  self)
```

I haven't used the SDK (though I know the guys from indoo.rs, nice fellas), so I don't know when that delegate method `setRoute` is called exactly, the documentation example seems to update a view to show the path.

**Edit**: I deleted the `setRoute` call in my example, because on second thought I began to wonder why you were calling this delegate method in the first place. It's a bad name for a delegate method, true (more like a setter), but if I understand the documentation correctly, this is called *for* you, hence it's a delegate method. You're supposed to call `Indoors.instance().routeFromLocation(start, toLocation: end, delegate:  self)`. I assume, that then at some point calls your delegate's `setRoute`.

Comment: You're welcome. I can't try it out myself, but it really looks like you shouldn't call `setRoute` yourself. A really bad name for a delegate method, it should say something like `delegateDidSetRoute` or so. I suggest setting a breakpoint and make sure that it gets called after `Indoors.instance().routeFromLocation(start, toLocation: end, inBuilding: building, delegate: self)` is called, to make sure. You might also ensure `Indoors.instance()` properly works and gives whatever the instance is supposed to be.

Comment: There is a delegate called RoutingDelegate and i confirmed to it